# Can I use somename from select field as somename in where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the products with totalQuantity less than alterQuantity.

```
$this->db
->select("products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.unit, products.price, sum(warehouses_products.quantity) as totalQuantity, products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity")
->from('products')
->where('alertQuantity >=', 'totalQuantity')
->join('warehouses_products', 'products.id=warehouses_products.product_id, 'left')
->group_by("products.id");
```

I am getting error that **Unknown column 'alertQuantity' in 'where clause'** if I alertQuantity with products.alert_quantity in where clause I get **Unknown column 'totalQuantity' in 'where clause'**  this one i don't know how to change as this is sum of quantity. Can you please help me regarding this?

**MY QUESTION:**
I have select alert_quantity as alertQuantity and sum(quantity) as totalQuantity

**Can i use alterQuantity and totalQuantity in where clause?**

**Table structure**

Products

id, code, name, unit, price, alert_quantity

warehouses_products

id, product_id, warehouse_id, quantity

---

**Found** 
 I can't use totalQuantity Is there any other idea that how can i compare the products.alert_quantity with sum(warehouses.products.quantity)?

Answer (score 0):

TRy this::

```
select 
products.id as productid, 
products.code as code, 
products.name, products.unit, 
products.price, 
sum(products.alert_quantity) as totalQuantity, 
products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity
from products

LEFT join warehouses_products on products.id=warehouses_products.product_id
where products.alert_quantity>= totalQuantity
group_by products.id
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group_by products.id) ORDER BY (select productid, `code`, `products`.`name`, `'

Comment: In my query there is not any closed brackets after the GROUP by Products.id, please paste the entire query along with the order by clause

Comment: Sorry this is error - Unknown column 'alertQuantity' in 'where clause'

select products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.unit, products.price, sum(warehouses_products.quantity) as totalQuantity, products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity from products LEFT join warehouses_products on products.id=warehouses_products.product_id where alertQuantity >= totalQuantity GROUP BY products.id

Comment: Please paste the table structure of the products table

Comment: totalQuantity is unknown I have found that this can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

try using second parameter of select, like
change

```
$this->db
->select("products.id as productid, products.code as code, 
products.name, products.unit, products.price, 
sum(warehouses_products.quantity) as totalQuantity, 
products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity")
```

to

```
$this->db
->select("products.id as productid, products.code as code, 
products.name, products.unit, products.price, 
sum(warehouses_products.quantity) as totalQuantity, 
products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity", FALSE)
```

And close the quotes in join part

**Edit**, try re-ordering you statements, like:

```
$this->db
->select("products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.unit, products.price, sum(warehouses_products.quantity) as totalQuantity, products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity", FALSE)
->from('products')
->join('warehouses_products', 'products.id=warehouses_products.product_id', 'left')
->where('alertQuantity >=', 'totalQuantity')
->group_by("products.id");
```

Comment: Tried same error Unknown column 'alertQuantity' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Saleem try changing your where clause, as in added code in answer

Comment: Already tried this :( but same The Problem is its not allowing me to use alertQuantiy and totalQuantity that i am using in select as

Comment: @Saleem, not sure but could you try reordering your statements, like select --> from --> join --> where ... as in my edited answer

Comment: I tried all and found that SQL is evaluated backwards, from right to left. So the where clause is parsed and evaluate prior to the select clause. Because of this the aliasing of u_name to user_name as not yet occurred. :(

Comment: @Saleem, instead of using where clause could you try with having clause, like $this->db->having('alertQuantity >=', 'totalQuantity', FALSE); ... HOPE THAT WORKS